# Should I declare Jackson's ObjectMapper every time I need it?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a multithread Java application, where I use the Jackson library. Everytime I need the ObjectMapper I declare it in the classes where I need to use it. Sometimes I customize this ObjectMapper with objectMapper.configure(), but not always.
Is this a bad practice? Is there any way to declare it only one or two times?

Comment: Thread safety is addressed in the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). Two main options are offered if you need to use different configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the instantiation new ObjectMapper() takes quite long, so you should definitely reuse the object rather than creating it every time before repeated use.

I usually declare it like a logger in the class that'S using it (but of course it depends on your specific requirements whether this makes sense for you):

```
  private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Jackson `ObjectMapper` has lots of different configuration parameters for different circumstances, and while it's okay to share an instance across threads for operations, it is entirely ordinary to need substantially different setups (for example, when you are consuming a REST API that uses `camel_case` naming, or even using a YAML or CSV mapper).

For this reason, I do not recommend making `ObjectMapper` a bean any more than I recommend making `Function<Foo, Bar>` or `String` beans; the bean type isn't specific enough.

Instead, the `ObjectMapper` is much more like *part of the API*, because settings such as "use `camel_case`" or "write dates as ISO 8601 strings" aren't like cache expiration times, they reflect a fixed part of the contract.

I recommend creating *factory methods* that will build new instances based on requirements specific to use cases. These methods can live in libraries shared across your company to enforce consistent mapping regarding variable naming, date/time handling, etc.:

```
public static ObjectMapper companyObjectMapper() {
    // company-wide standard configuration
    ...
}

public static ObjectMapper specificRestApiObjectMapper() {
    // uses Unix epoch for dates and camel_case
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to reuse objectmapper wherever possible. Because it’s threadsafe. If any classes require different configurations in objectmapper, only then instantiate separate objectmapper for such classes.

I recommend not to have multiple instances of same config.